# Link to open specific excel sheet

Tags: excel, hyperlink, worksheet

I need to send a link from vba to my email in order to let me open a specific excel sheet.
I've used the following link:

```
<A HREF=""file://W:\firme\2020-08-17 16_40_01 - VINCOLANTE-KWICK - PMI STAGIONALI INVERNALI.xlsm#Foglio1"">link</a>
```

this give me: URL error. Impossible to find specified file

when I'll try to open only excel without specify the sheet name everything is ok:

```
<A HREF=""file://W:\firme\2020-08-17 16_40_01 - VINCOLANTE-KWICK - PMI STAGIONALI INVERNALI.xlsm"">link</a>
```

Open specific excel sheet when file is "xlsx" work without error.

Maybe is an outlook problem because using this hyperlink:

```
\\mypath\invernali.xlsm#'Foglio2'!A1
```

works well in Word but not in outlook...

I'm using Excel 2016.